# Prevent multiple submit of a textarea data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea validation code that only submits when the textarea is not empty. The below code works perfectly but how can I prevent the content in the textarea from submitting multiple times pressing return on the keyboard multiple times in succession?

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13 && $.trim($(this).val())) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        send();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just disable the textarea - that's the simplest way to handle it.

Comment: how? please show me

Comment: @Archer that may stop the field being included in the form data though - depending on how the OP sends the form

Comment: So he could use `readonly` instead.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki sounds like you have an answer :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but i can't post it now :( go ahead and show him.

Comment: please sirs  and code seniors!!!

Comment: as suggested, inside the IF statement, add $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');

Comment: it did not work. On hitting the enter keyboard multiple times, it submits the data as much as those times

Answer (score 0):

```
window.formWasSubmitted = false;

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13 && $.trim($(this).val()) && !window.formWasSubmitted) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        window.formWasSubmitted = true;
        send();
    }
});
```

Comment: this is working but it disables the textarea thereafter

Comment: Oops, I removed the statement which made the textarea read-only.

Comment: yes! if I enter content the second time it does not submit on pressing the enter keyboard

Comment: I don't understand your use-case. Perhaps you could update your question with more details.